# HASONEFILTER SUMX total not calculating correctly

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am creating a Power BI measure that sums up averages so I have used the HASONEVALUE SUMX method but the total doesn't match what the actual sum would be if you just add up the information.  Here is the measure:

[image]

And here is the results:

[image]

The total shows 31,654.25 but if you add up the rows you actually get 22,962.33.  I am wondering if there is something wrong with my measure or if it is an issue of me not realizing it is pulling in additional information I'm not aware of.

Comment: It seems odd to sum averages like this. What is the Total row supposed to represent? Does 22,962.33 mean something useful?

Comment: We are looking to aggregate monthly usage as an average per month by contract but we want to know the total average usage for the given time frame.  So we can see each month we are doing a total average of 22962.33 and can look at the individual contracts that make up that total.

Comment: 22,962.33 doesn't give you total average usage unless all of the contracts have the same number of invoices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to @Alexis Olson, the average in a row is for the group, the total count is for entire datatable.

Below table is grouped by column A. Sum of averages is not equal to total average

[image]

Comment: Hello Rajesh, I see what you are saying but what I am looking for is the Sum Avg to equal the the sum of the averages which it does in your example: 3+5+6=14 but in mine when using the data in the model 9344.11+12772.72+845.50 != 31654.25 and I'm not sure why it's not just adding up the values in the table

Comment: The 4.62 value is what gets displayed in the Power Bi visual. It is the total avg and not sum of averages.

Comment: @Matt, you're basically computing 4.62 + 4.62 + 4.62 from this example in your measure.

Comment: If you look more closely, the row in Power BI is named total, not really sum

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  I completely understand what is going on now!  Is there a way to add up the individual averages?

Comment: Not sure how to display sum in the visual itself, maybe this could help https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/visual-total-not-matching-sum-of-individual-row/td-p/1183586

Answer (score 1):

This is calculating the average over all of the selected contracts and then summing that same value for each selected contract. (When you define a variable, it's treated as a constant in the remainder of the measure definition.)

Comment: I apologize Alexis, I'm not sure I follow what you are saying.